# JSLint and my Javascript - Best practices on making this script conform

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

A function I put together (which runs but doesn't validate under JSLint) is as follows:

```
function toNumber(str)
{
 str = str.toString().replace(/[^0123456789.-]/g,'');
 if (str == "") {return 0;}
 return parseFloat(str);
}
```

This is intended to take any given string and convert it to a number for use elsewhere in my javascript.  Example runs as follows:

toNumber("5") => 5

toNumber("3,276") => 3276

toNumber("-14b396Z") => -14396

The problem here is when I try to validate it with JSLint I get two errors I cannot resolve.

```
 line 25 character 36  str = str.toString().replace(/[^0123456789.-]/g,'');
  Insecure '^'.
 line 25 character 48  str = str.toString().replace(/[^0123456789.-]/g,'');
  Unescaped '-'.
```

I know I can turn on the "and [^...] in /RegExp/" to ignore the first error, but that still leaves me with the second.  What would be the best way to solve both errors?  I figure if I'm going to rewrite this anyway I might as well do so for both errors instead of just turning a blind eye to the 'Insecure' nature of using ^.

Thank you,
- Aaron Nichols

Comment: Just use a more sensible tool like http://jshint.com instead. It's designed by folks of whom I have greater confidence of their mental stability.

Comment: AFAIK **all** regexp engines treat the dash/hyphen as non-special if it's the **first** character in the character class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, to start, does `toNumber` handle, say, "123.12.3" and "123.-123" like you intend?

But if we're not worried about stuff like that, and just want to replicate what you've got initially, this isn't too difficult.

What JSLint is telling you is that **a regular expression shouldn't say what you *don't* want, but should instead define what you *do* want.**

That's *really* easy to do in this case.  Instead of saying, "I want to replace anything that's **not** a digit, dot, or dash, and see if I've got nothing left", say, "I want everything, from the start of the string to the end, to **be** a digit, dot, or dash, or I don't want a match at all".

I'm not a big fan of multiple returns, and JSLint will give you a `Unnecessary 'else' after disruption` if I `return parseFloat(str);` after the `null` check, so let's put in a return var too.

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true */
function toNumber2(str)
{
    var retVal = 0;
    if (null !== str.match(/^[0123456789.\-]+$/))
    {
        retVal = parseFloat(str);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

So I did that a little quickly, but I think that's the same as what you initially wanted.

I understand the rule is kinda overkill in your very specific situation, but it is very easy to let unintentional matches slip through when you "not" `^` a sequence in more complicated cases. In those more complicated cases, this rule can be a logical lifesaver.